# using the parameters in Alteryx workflows

Tags: alteryx

I am fairly new to the Alteryx. 
I would like to create a process/workflow in Alteryx to import a file from a specified location but that should be controlled by the input parameters.

Kindly help me in this.

Thanks,
RTJ

Comment: Look into "analytic apps".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
Could you please let me know, Is there a way to control the input file location in the data input tool using the parameters

Comment: Yes, they have a "Dynamic Input" tool which can be used; or also when writing apps or macros, you can have even finer control over the values behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect an Interface Tool:File Browse via an Interface Tool:Action to change the file selected to an In/Out:Input Data:

[image]

You will then want to run the workflow using the Run As Analytic App:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the developer tool category, you'll find the Dynamic Input tool. This works much like the standard Input Data tool, but can take records in to modify the data it collects.
https://help.alteryx.com/2018.2/DynamicInput.htm

It sounds like you have files in a standard location, but want to be able to dynamically select the ones to load.
Let's say you have a collection of sales files in the format "Sales_20190718.csv" but want to only get sales information for certain dates as specified in your workflow. You can point your Dynamic Input tool to the Sales_20190718.csv, and have it replace the "20190718" part with whatever input you gave to the tool before querying the information.

You could get a similar result by using wildcards in a basic Input Data tool by pulling data from "Sales_*", and ticking the "Output File Name as Field" box. This would load all your sales data (which could take some time) but then you could filter to the relevant files using the new FileName field.